# Bypassing the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider for a specific type in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a type "Content" (from a custom CMS) that must **not** be validated by the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider. I don't want to remove the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider from the providers since I need it for all other types.

I thought of creating a custom ModelValidatorProvider which inherited from DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider and in the only public entry point (the method GetValidators) check if the containerType is of type "Content" then return an empty collection of validators and let another custom ModelValidatorProvider handle the validation for this specific type. But my friends at Microsoft decided to sealed this method in the AssociatedValidatorProvider which is the base class of DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.

Do you see any other way of skipping the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider for a specific type?

If not, could you vote for my suggestion over here: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3571625-remove-sealed-on-method-getvalidators-of-type-asso

This is a discussion from someone else facing a similar problem: http://forums.asp.net/t/1751517.aspx/1

Comment: If you don't want your type `Content` validated then don't use that type. Instead of create a new type `ContentViewModel` what you can use in your mvc views and actions without any validation. Of course you need to deal with the mapping between `Content` and `ContentViewModel` but there are tools like AutoMapper which can help you with that.

Comment: This type is at the center of a CMS I'm building and I have built a complete ModelMetatadataProvider so that a form can be rendered with @Html.EditorForModel()... I would not ask this question if I could use another type. And I know what AutoMapper is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couldn't you just inherit directly from `ModelValidatorProvider`? You could then modify `GetValidators` as you wish. For example:

```
public class CustomValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    private readonly DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider _provider = new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider();

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (metadata.ModelType == typeof(Content) || metadata.ContainerType == typeof(Content))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidator>();
        }

        return _provider.GetValidators(metadata, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is I had tried something like this but got lost while trying to call the GetValidators method of the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider. For some reason I can't explain, I was trying to call the overloaded one with the IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, which I obviously didn't have... Now it is working. I just have to test if it breaks the behavior of the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider. Thanks!